# Join 2 tables where a column is RegEx

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, join

I am trying to join 2 tables in SQL Server, where one table has the actual name, and the other has a regex.

For example,

Table A looks something like

```
Name, A
apple1, 1
apple2, 2
orange1, 3
orange2, 4 
grape1, 5
grape2, 6
```

Table B

```
NameRegex, B
^(apple.*|orange.*), 10
^(grape.*), 20
```

I would like to join the tables and get

```
Name, NameRegex, A, B
apple1, ^(apple.*|orange.*), 1, 10
apple2, ^(apple.*|orange.*), 2, 10
orange1, ^(apple.*|orange.*), 3, 10
orange2, ^(apple.*|orange.*), 4, 10
grape1, ^(grape.*), 5, 20
grape2, ^(grape.*), 6, 20
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend modifying the design of your database so that the TableA has a foreign key reference to the relevant row in TableB.

Comment: There is not much you can do.  SQL Server does not natively support regular expressions.